# Strange behavior with label span and italic font attribute

Tags: html, xamarin, label, italic

trying to follow Xamarin tutorial for a label view at :
[Label Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/label/?tabs=vswin&tutorial-step=3)

when applying italic font attribute in a span tag , while setting the size of the label text to any value in the label tag. the text size did not get applied to the text in the span with italic attribute.

```
<StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,25">
    <Label FontSize="50" TextColor="Blue">
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="underlined text" TextDecorations="Underline" />
                <Span Text=", emphasized" FontAttributes="Italic" />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

[output from android emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/label/?tabs=vswin&tutorial-step=3)

Comment: Hi , I have submitted as an issue in GitHub [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8859) , you can follow up it .By the way , I also found a workaround and shared in answer , you can have a look at it when have time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found that it when the span with `Italic` attribute the `FontSize` of **Label** can not work. However , I found a **WorkAround** for this , you can set `FontSize` of this Span to solve it .

Have a look at follow code:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,25">
    <Label FontSize="50" TextColor="Blue">
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="underlined text" TextDecorations="Underline" />
                <Span Text=", emphasized" FontSize="50" FontAttributes="Italic" />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

The effect :

[image]

I think next version of Xamarin Forms will fix it as soon as possible .

Comment: thanks , i also did this as a workaround and hope it to be fixed

Comment: @Sh.Raai Glad be helpful , remember to mark it when you have time :)